# Is it possible to use Oculus Quest 2 as a multi-monitor on a work computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-reality, oculus-rift

I'm trying to find a way to use my Oculus Quest 2 on my work laptop. The programs suggest to do this (Immersed, VRDesktop,...) are sadly not on my companies approved programs list.

Is there a way to setup my Oculus Quest 2 so that when I plug a USB C into both the Oculus and my computer, my computer thinks I've just plugged in a KVM / Laptop docking station which is connected to multiple monitors?

Recently my KVM I've been using to connect two monitors to my laptop has died and I'm looking at options to replace it.

Comment: Any solution I might be able to provide would require software, which you can't use, since it won't be approved software.

Comment: I was thinking of installing something on the Oculus so that it would emulate a docking station. If there is something that would do this I would not need to install anything on my work laptop.

Comment: Any peripheral requires drivers, and in the case of a peripheral as complex as the Oculus, it would require a complex driver that likely includes required software.

Answer (score 0):

After some help and research I've found https://virtc.app/
I'll have to do more research to see if it is safe to use for work.